# "Looks good" review reason not content related?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

After reading about [skipping](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip) in the review queue, I noticed that despite what is being said there, I relatively often use skip and was wondering why that is the case.

I then got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343801/converting-int-to-string-in-a-textbox#23343840) in my review queue, and upon reading the context, I was wondering if using skip  is really the right thing.

My thoughts here were "Well, if the code was correct, it wouldn't be the best of answers, but I think it is wrong. Lets downvote, but this shouldn't be in the review queue as an item for deletion". So I read the possible actions:

- **Looks Good** if nothing is wrong with this answer
- **Edit** if you can fix all the problems with this answer
- **Recommend Deletion** to recommend that this answer be deleted
- **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next item

I would not chose *Recommend Deletion* because I think this is a case that should be handled by downvoting.

I would not chose *Edit* because this would totally make a new answer out of it.

I would not chose *Looks Good* because, well, it does not look good. It says *if nothing is wrong with this answer* but there is something wrong: the information itself.

So I am not sure what to click. This should naturally lead to clicking *Skip* but that feels wrong, because then the item would still be exactly in the same state for reviewing, why what I want to say is "Please put this out of the review queue, it doesn't belong here".

So the question here is:

Is the *Looks Good* action only for "stylistic" issues that are orthogonal to reasons why you would downvote? If so, can we possibly make this a bit clearer in the text by mentioning that if all you would do is downvoting, the right action might be *Looks Good*?

Comment: Well, even without a content change it could use an edit. P.s. you're linking to an answer but talk about a question. I'm referring to the linked answer here.

Comment: If the answer is *factually* wrong, just use 'looks good'. The point is to teach users about how Stack Overflow *works*, and to weed out spam and other non-answers. The merits of the content of actual answers are not under review here.

Comment: @Bart: Yeah, I meant the answer, corrected link text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Looks good" doesn't mean that this is a great post of amazing quality.  It means that the post is good enough to meet the *bare minimum* quality standards of the site.  It is not such complete garbage as to require deletion, nor does it need to be edited for it to be something that's good enough to not need to be scoured from the face of the earth.